# PayPal React shows extra buttons after changing amount

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

**WITHOUT react-paypal-button-v2 ~~~has an ovehead of 60KB**

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826646/im-trying-to-make-react-paypal-button-that-change-the-billing-amount-on-props-c?rq=1) but they suggest **react-paypal-button-v2**

I'm Trying to make a React PayPal button that changes the billing amount on props change.

I call the following component with props price and every time the price change i would like to re-render the button to update the actual price. **WITHOUT react-paypal-button-v2**

```
const PaypalForm = props => {
  let paypalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {      
    window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: "test",
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "USD",
                  value: props.price
                }
              }
            ]
          });
        },
        onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await actions.order.capture();
          console.log(order);
        },
        onError: err => {
          setError(err);
          console.error(err);
        }
      })
      .render(paypalRef.current);
  }, [props.price]);

  return (
    <Row className="justify-content-center">
      {error && <div>Uh oh, an error occurred! {error.message}</div>}
      <div ref={paypalRef} />
    </Row>
  );
};
```

Everything is working except that a new button is created and added in the bottom of old one at each props change. I would like my new button to replace the old one. **Without using react-paypal-button-v2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(window.myButton) window.myButton.close();
    window.myButton = window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: "test",
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "USD",
                  value: props.price
                }
              }
            ]
          });
        },
        onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await actions.order.capture();
          console.log(order);
        },
        onError: err => {
          setError(err);
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    window.myButton.render(paypalRef.current);
```

However, you do *not* actually need to re-render the button on price change!

You can do `value: document.getElementById('...').value` or similar (or whatever variable or function call you need)

In your example, if `props.price` returns the (new/current) desired value when the button is clicked, then that value will be used.

Basically, **the `createOrder` function isn't called until you click a button.**